# Using jdb to step inside object construction during execution

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

I use `jdb` for my Java development. For my application I have two classes: `WordUniverseTest` and `WordUniverse`, and the main method is contained in `WordUniverseTest`. When I execute `WordUniverseTest` inside of `jdb`, I construct a `WordUniverse` object called `obj` inside of the `main` method.

But I do not know how to have `jdb` leave the `WordUniverseTest` class and step inside `WordUniverse` **while** `obj` is being constructed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a regular breakpoint there `stop at` and then when you are actually on the line (call `list` to verify), you can call `step into`.

As long as all your classes are known to jdb, it is going to work, I tested it.

Comment: I tried this and got `Step completed: "thread=main", jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(), line=581 bci=1` but the `jdb` didn't take me to the constructor.

Comment: When you call a `list` afterwards, you should see, that you are in the constructor. What do you see instead?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, and although Gergely Bacso didn't give the full answer, he did lead me to find the full answer.

`jdb` uses a different procedure for stepping into methods versus stepping into constructors. To step into a method, you have to do what Gergely Basco said, which is set a breakpoint at where the method is called and then `step into`. But for stepping into a constructor you must say `stop in ClassName.<init>` (with brackets). Saying that command will take you inside of the constructor.